# How to create Global Variable per hosted service in .Net core

Tags: .net-core, global-variables, asp.net-core-hosted-services

**How to create a global variable that can be unique per hosted service execution?**

Complete Code:
https://github.com/matvi/dotnet-hosted-services

**The problem:**

When running hosted services is difficult to keep track of the execution without logs. In order to keep track of the execution of the hosted services I implemented logs with a unique traceId (GUID)

The problem is that the TraceLogId is being created per Task using Static Memory and when 2 task runs at the same time the first TraceLogId gets overridden by the second task.

**Is there any way to avoid the traceLogId being overridden?**

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static Guid TraceLogId { get; set; }
}

public class Task1Service : ITask1Service
{
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        GlobalVariables.TraceLogId = Guid.NewGuid();
        Console.WriteLine($"Task1 executing with traceLogId = {GlobalVariables.TraceLogId}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Task1 will wait 5 seconds = {GlobalVariables.TraceLogId}");
        await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken);
        Console.WriteLine($"Task1 ending = {GlobalVariables.TraceLogId}");
    }
}

public class Task2Service : ITask2Service
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task2 executing");
            GlobalVariables.TraceLogId = Guid.NewGuid();
            Console.WriteLine($"Task2 executing with traceLogId = {GlobalVariables.TraceLogId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Task2 ending = {GlobalVariables.TraceLogId}");
        }
    }
```

When the code is executed Task1 gets a TraceLogId but when it finishes it has the traceLogId that was assigned in Task2.
[image]

```
    using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Cronos;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace HostedServicesPoc.Tasks
{
    public abstract class CronJobServiceBase : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ILogger _log;
        private readonly HostedServiceTaskSettingsBase _hostedServiceTaskSettingsBase;
        private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
        private readonly CronExpression _expression;
        private readonly TimeZoneInfo _timeZoneInfo;

        protected CronJobServiceBase(IOptions<HostedServiceTaskSettingsBase> hostedServiceSettings, ILogger<CronJobServiceBase> log)
        {
            _log = log;
            _hostedServiceTaskSettingsBase = hostedServiceSettings?.Value;
            _expression = CronExpression.Parse(_hostedServiceTaskSettingsBase.CronExpressionTimer, CronFormat.Standard);
            _timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
        }

        public virtual async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _log.LogInformation($"{GetType()} is Starting");
            if (_hostedServiceTaskSettingsBase.Active)
            {
                await ScheduleJob(cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _log.LogInformation($"{GetType()} is Stopping");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task ScheduleJob(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var next = _expression.GetNextOccurrence(DateTimeOffset.Now, _timeZoneInfo);
            if (next.HasValue)
            {
                var delay = next.Value - DateTimeOffset.Now;
                if (delay.TotalMilliseconds <= 0)   // prevent non-positive values from being passed into Timer
                {
                    await ScheduleJob(cancellationToken);
                }
                _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(delay.TotalMilliseconds);
                _timer.Elapsed += async (sender, args) =>
                {
                    _timer.Dispose();  // reset and dispose timer
                    _timer = null;

                    if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        await ExecuteTaskAsync(cancellationToken);
                    }

                    if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        await ScheduleJob(cancellationToken);    // reschedule next
                    }
                };
                _timer.Start();
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        protected virtual async Task ExecuteTaskAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool dispose)
        {
            try
            {
                if (dispose)
                {
                    _timer?.Dispose();
                }
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TaskServices:**

```
    public class Task1HostedService : CronJobServiceBase
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public Task1HostedService(
        IOptions<Task1HostedServiceSettings> hostedServiceSettings,
        ILogger<CronJobServiceBase> log,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(hostedServiceSettings, log)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    
    protected override async Task ExecuteTaskAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var task1Service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITask1Service>();
        await task1Service.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this particular case, I'm not undestanding why you need to have the TraceLogId on a static class, can't you move the "Guid TraceLogId " property into the Task1Service and Task2Service classes so each time you start one of those a new id is generated and kept for the instance? If you have a global static variable it seems pretty obvious that if the second task is started it will overwrite the previous ID and so each times a new task is started (based on your code)

Comment: The reason is that I share that traceLogId through multiple services and methods. This is just a small example of a big project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a scoped value for this; `AsyncLocal<T>` fits the bill.

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
  private static AsyncLocal<Guid> _TraceLogId = new();
  public static Guid TraceLogId => _TraceLogId.Value;
  public static IDisposable SetTraceLogId(Guid value)
  {
    var oldValue = _TraceLogId.Value;
    _TraceLogId.Value = value;
    return Disposable.Create(() => _TraceLogId.Value = oldValue);
  }
}

public class Task1Service : ITask1Service
{
  public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    using var traceIdScope = GlobalVariables.SetTraceLogId(Guid.NewGuid());
    Console.WriteLine($"Task1 executing with traceLogId = {GlobalVariables.TraceLogId}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Task1 will wait 5 seconds = {GlobalVariables.TraceLogId}");
    await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken);
    Console.WriteLine($"Task1 ending = {GlobalVariables.TraceLogId}");
  }
}
```

This uses `Disposable` from my [Disposables](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Disposables) library.

Comment: This works so well. Thank youuuu! It's cool that you point to your own library. Can you briefly explain how is that this works???

Comment: AsyncLocal values (when used in this pattern) provide a value that is scoped over some code (as opposed to global or thread local values). Full details are [on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html).